# why does name of database appear in the text input?

Tags: php

I create a php file in my database which just includes some text input. I don't have any php script in the file. So why the name of my database appears in the text inputs?

This is source code (that is all I got but the web requires to have more text +.+) :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Log in</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />

        <style>
            .container {
                border:1px solid grey;
                padding: 20px;
                margin: 20px auto;
                display: table;

            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Home<li>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li>
                <form method="post" action="main.php">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" /> 
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" /> 
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" />
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class = "container">
        <form method="post">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" /> 
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" /> 
            <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" /> 
            <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" /> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" />           
        </form>
    </div>  

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you typed it in there at some point? Try another browser or doing a hard refresh. Could be your browser remembering the text. Or is your database called "Email" / "Password"? :)

Comment: My database has different name. I tried in another browser and the database name does not appear at all. So how to make the browser forget the name of my database?

Comment: You could try `autocomplete="off"` or http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Comment: autocomplete="off" makes the name disappear but it still appear in the recommendation if I click the input. One more thing, it remember nothing but only the name of my database.

Comment: Add that to the form and all the inputs.